# TSQL XML parsing using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an XML structure like below:

```
<theData>
<account>111111111</account>
<data>
  <type>Premier</type>
  <action>Stuff</action>
</data>
</theData>`
```

Since Account is a parent node, how would I get that using the below Select statement when I have already defined the nodes as theData/data to be looking in?

`INSERT INTO table (account, type, action) 
        SELECT ParamValues.x2.value('account[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)'),
                ParamValues.x2.value('type[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                ParamValues.x2.value('action[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
        FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/theData/data') AS ParamValues(x2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ParamValues.x2.value('type[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
    ParamValues.x2.value('action[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') ,
    ParamValues.x2.value('../account[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') 
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/theData/data') AS ParamValues(x2)`
```

Comment: is there a reason account is included twice?

Comment: I think he skipped first one. You can take only one.

Comment: strange, it doesnt pull anything, just an empty field